# How to Load JSON Build of Solidity Contract into Javascipt

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain

I'm thinking there's gotta be a way to load the `abi` (or the entire `JSON` `build` file) of a `smart contract` into my front-end `Javascript` app after compilation *automatically* - meaning via some kind of `config` script.
That way I don't have to copy-paste the `abi` into the `Javascript`  code *manually*, after every single edit and compilation I make on my `smart-contract.`

But how?

**NOTE:** I'm *not* using `Node.js` here, we're talking pure front-end vanilla `javascript` file.

`Webpack`'s website clearly states that: beginning with Webpack version 2.0.0 `json loaders` are no longer needed.
Well right now I'm trying this and getting an error:

```
import * as contractArtifact from "../build/contracts/MySmartContract.json"
```

The error is:

```
import declarations may only appear at top level of a module
```

For what it's worth, my code for instantiating the contract in my Javascript code - which works perfectly - is as follows:

```
contractArtifact = {
    "contractName": "MyContract",
    "abi": [
      {
        "inputs": [
          {
            "internalType": "string",
            "name": "name",
            "type": "string"
          },
     ...
     ...etc...
} 

contractABI = contractArtifact["abi"];

// Get the Contract's ADDRESS:
network = Object.keys(contractArtifact.networks)[0];
contractAddress = contractArtifact.networks[network].address;

// Now instantiate the Contract using the ABI and the Address:
contractInstance = new web3Instance.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);
```

So this works perfectly - I just don't want to have to manually copy-paste that entire `JSON` file into here every single time I make the tiniest change to and then compile my smart-contract.

Comment: Turning an answer (now deleted) into a comment: The `import` and `require` statements are designated to be used for JS files only. They can be used in order to load **code** from another file into your JS script. What you are trying to do is to load **data** from another file into your JS script. If your JSON file started with `module.exports = `, then your import attempt would probably work. But that would effectively turn it from a JSON file into a JS file (regardless of the extension used).

Comment: On NodeJS, with `const fs = require("fs");`, you could simply do:

Comment: `const contractArtifact = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("../build/contracts/MySmartContract.json", {encoding: "utf8"}));`

Comment: I don't think that you can do this (reading a file) from code running in a browser, so you'll need to do have a script loading the contents of that JSON file into your JS file dynamically (before sending it to the client side).

Answer (score 1):

In a js file use this:

```
fetch('./build/contracts/Contract.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```